# issue in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, url, anchor

I have a html file consist of following code -

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<nav id="headnav" class="menu"> <a id="logo" href="index.php"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/benjigarner/softdimension/256/Image-ready-CS-2-icon.png"></a>
        <ul>            
          <li><a data-scroll id="t_link" href="#feature">Feature</a></li>
          <li><a data-scroll id="d_link" href="#thedrink">The Drink</a></li>
          <li><a data-scroll id="o_link" href="#recipes">Recipes</a></li>                           
        </ul>    
    </nav>    
<div id="home" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
                <div id="poloclub_open">
                      <div class="space"></div>
                      <img src="http://cdn1.yourstory.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Image-1.jpg" />
                      <div class="space"></div>
                </div>
                          <div id="paratext1">
                          <blockquote class="ani"><a href="#trailer">PRESENTING POLO CLUB</a></blockquote>
                          </div><!--paratext1--> 
                </div>
        <!--thedrink-->                     
      <section id="feature">
             <div id="trail">
                                      <div id="videocontrol">
                                      <a id="play-pause" class="play"><img src="http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/System/clearDisk%20iconset%20part%20I/audio%20pause.png"/></a>
                                      </div>
                                    <video id="video_background" preload="auto" volume="5">
                                              <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4"/>
                                              <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm"/>
                                              <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv"/>    
                                    </video>                               

                                <img id="image_background" src="http://www.gettyimages.com/CMS/StaticContent/1357941082241_new_banner-700x465.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />                           
                                </div><!--trail-->                      
</section><!--feature-->
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
<a id="abc">abc</a>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
<a id="123">123</a>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
<h4>test</h4>
</br>
</body>
</html>
```

Copy and paste the above code in a notepad and save it as `abc.htm`.
After saving open the html file and add fragment `#abc` to URL to focus.

`e.g - //path/abc.htm#abc`

After focusing it does not focus to that exact location.. infact, page moves a bit upward after anchoring to text "abc".

Why this happens?

Please Help..

Comment: You included id="abc" in anchor tag, hence it is moving to that location

Answer (score 0):

You have some images without height/width attributes or styles. Your browser is scrolling to the anchor before the images load. The images are then changing the position of the content you linked to.

Comment: Different browsers handle it differently.

Comment: Tell the browser what the dimensions of the images are.